# Logistic Model always giving same output for all the inputs of training and test examples

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am training a logistic regression model on `Iris dataset` which has 3 classes of output using Tensorflow.

I've divided my training set into 75% training and 25% test set.

On training the model, `Y_hat` is the  prediction on training set. On printing the output(Y_hat), I see that the model is predicting `1` for all the input (shape (None,4)).

Also, on testing the model with again `Y_hat` as the model prediction, it is still showing `1` for all the test set input, which is inevitable as the model is poorly doing on the train set.

Here is the code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris=datasets.load_iris()
type(iris)

X=iris.data[:]
X=X.astype(np.float32)
Y=iris.target[:]
Y=Y.astype(np.float32)
print("x=",type(X)," Y=",type(Y))
print("X.shape=",X.shape,"Y.shape=",Y.shape)
Y=Y.reshape(Y.shape[0],1)
print("Y.shape=",Y.shape)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=23, test_size=0.25, stratify=Y)
print("Size")
print("X_train=",X_train.shape)
print("Y_train=",Y_train.shape)
print("X_test=",X_test.shape)
print("Y_test=",Y_test.shape)

#Variables
W=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4,1]),dtype=tf.float32)
b=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1,1]),dtype=tf.float32)

#Placeholder
input_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,iris.data[:].shape[1]))
output_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,Y.shape[1]))

Y_hat=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input_,W)+b)

c=tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y_hat,logits=output_)
cost=tf.reduce_mean(c)

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

train=optimizer.minimize(cost)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    epochs=6
    for i in range(epochs):
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(Y_hat,feed_dict={input_:X_train})#,output_:Y_train})

        sess.run(train,feed_dict={input_:X_train,output_:Y_train})
        print(i,"Cost=",sess.run(cost,feed_dict={input_:X_train,output_:Y_train}))


    ytest=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(None,1))


    print(sess.run(Y_hat,feed_dict={input_:X_test}))

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y_hat,1), tf.argmax(ytest,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(Y_hat.shape)
    print("accuracy=",sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={input_:X_test,ytest:Y_test}))

    print("test_cost",sess.run(cost,feed_dict={input_:X_test,output_:Y_test}))
```

Here is the output with all the test set predictions :

```
x= <class 'numpy.ndarray'>  Y= <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
X.shape= (150, 4) Y.shape= (150,)
Y.shape= (150, 1)
Size
X_train= (112, 4)
Y_train= (112, 1)
X_test= (38, 4)
Y_test= (38, 1)
0 Cost= 0.377203
1 Cost= 0.377203
2 Cost= 0.377203
3 Cost= 0.377203
4 Cost= 0.377203
5 Cost= 0.377203
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
(?, 1)
accuracy= 1.0
test_cost 0.379477
```

Please explain the reason behind model prediction of `1` in all the cases. Is it because of the activation function or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems have some bugs. E.g: In `cross entropy` You pass your prediction (output of model) as `ground truth`. Change this line in your code to following:

```
logits = tf.matmul(input_, W) + b
Y_hat = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
c = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=output_y, logits=logits)
```

The way you calculate accuracy is not correct. You extract argmax for sigmoid output which is always the same. Change your sigmoid with softmax and change your labels to categorical.

Other things to consider:

1. Shuffle your data to make sure not biased over data.
2. Increase your epochs